# Dynamic marker icon on google maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps, coffeescript

I'm trying to achieve something like what AirBnb does with their map (see http://gyazo.com/c41bf6c5d9cf2b98c20e5696dbb26b85), 
where a price shows up on the icon.

Comment: where 's the code? what's the problem?

Comment: It's just the general maps marker code, I'm just wondering what I would need to add to make a square icon with custom text (set in javascript).

Answer (score 0):

you can use rich markers.....
https://code.google.com/p/google-maps-utility-library-v3/source/browse/trunk/richmarker/examples/richmarker.html?r=178